# How to combine php & python code in Python

Tags: php, python, forms, session, python-2.7

I’m looking for a way to combine my PHP code into my Python file. Maybe strange, but for me it would be quite helpfull. I simply want this part of PHP-code in Python because I don’t know how to rewrite it in Python :(

```
  function counter_winkelkar()
  {
    global $order;         
    global $refname;

if(isset( $_POST['clearknop'] )) 
{
    $_SESSION['count']= '0'; 
    unset($_SESSION['array_products']);   
    unset($_SESSION['array_counting_products']);
}

if (isset( $_POST['refname'] ))
{
    $_SESSION['count']= $_SESSION['count'] + $order;        
    print("$_SESSION[count]");
}
}

function products_winkelkar()
{
global $order;          
global $db;
global $refname;

if (!isset($_SESSION['array_products']) ) 
{
    $_SESSION['array_products'] = Array();
    $_SESSION['array_counting_products'] = Array();
}

if ($order != 'number' ) 
{
    array_push($_SESSION['array_products'],$refname);
    array_push($_SESSION['array_counting_products'],$order);
}   
}

function winkelkar()
{
counter_winkelkar();
products_winkelkar();
}

winkelkar();
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code is referencing $_POST and $_SESSION which says that it is expected to run in the context of a http server.  How does Python fit into this set up?

Comment: He wants it rewritten as python

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python web app I coded up using [web.py](http://webpy.org/) that approximates a counter that can be cleared.  Maybe it can help you port over your PHP:

```
import web

_SESSION = {}

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:        
    def POST(self):
        if 'clearknop' in web.input():
            _SESSION['count'] = 0
        else:
            if 'count' not in _SESSION: 
                _SESSION['count'] = 0
            _SESSION['count'] = _SESSION['count'] + 1

        return _SESSION['count']

    def GET(self):
        return """<form method='POST' action='/'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='clearknop'/> Clear
                    <input type='submit'/>
                  </form>"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

There is a lot missing form your PHP example to cover every feature in your question.  For instance how is `$order` populated and what kind of value does `$refname` contain?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reaction!! However I'm still looking for a solution. 'Order' is a number that the user selects when he wants to order a specific number of items. 'Refname' is the reference number of the product. I'm using a form (method="POST") where 'order' is the number selected by the user and 'refname' is the reference number that should be passed when pressing the "submit" button. I was looking for the cgi module to POST and GET these numbers to the shopping cart and the counter of the shopping cart but it won't work :(